# Basic Authentication doesn't call willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, basic-authentication

Setup:

- One Page iOS Application
- UIWebView with NSURLConnectionDelegate

Calling two different servers with Basic authentication leads to two different behaviors.

When accessing http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic/ via

```
_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic/"]]
```

the delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge`
```

gets called.

But when accessing [http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php](http://browserspy.dk/password.php) via

```
_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php"]];
```

The delegate method doesn't get called. **What is the difference between those two test sites?**

Comment: In first case server is challenging your request, in second case it isn't.

Comment: Doh, the link was wrong. Corrected it from http://browserspy.dk/password.php to http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php. Anyway, when calling the correct link the delegate methode is still NOT being called. What does technically happen in the second case?